# Установка ODAC на visual studio 2019

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, oracle, visual-studio-2019

Всем привет.

На официальном сайте установщик только для 2017 студии и более ранних. Скачал, попытался установить, получил ошибку. [image: Фото ошибки]

В логе написано, что вызывается исключение:
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: Это расширение не может быть установлено ни для одного из установленных продуктов.

Нужно ли устанавливать 2017 студию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, разработчики ODAC собирались заниматься поддержкой под VS2019, вот [пост](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4210958) с сайта коммьюнити, но пока что версии под 2019 нет.
Поэтому да, придется ставить VS2017.